# Which types of Javascript (Angular2) errors stop the page from finishing rendering

Tags: javascript, angular, error-handling

I'm new to Angular2 and have been charged with developing "robust error handling".  So far I've followed the simplistic examples (console.logging) for adding custom error handling.  But sometimes, if the page completely stops loading due to the error, we will want to redirect the user.

However sometimes, as below, although there are errors, the page otherwise loads completely.  Are there are only certain types of errors that stop the page from completely loading?  [One of the following 6 types perhaps?](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/handling-javascript-errors-by-type.html#fbid=mwnKlcLC62n)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Any error can stop your page from rendering, depending on where it occurs in your process. Any error can fail to be caught if it is in a callback or other asynchronous action.

Be careful with terms like *"robust error handling"* - I've seen huge commercial projects that claim just that, but actually just silently truck over loads of issues, kind of like `on error resume next`.

I find the golden rules are:

1. If your app can continue through an exception (such as getting corrupt JSON data from a non-essential service) then that specific case should always be explicitly handled.
2. Otherwise a unexpected exception should always break something visible.

That second rule is counter intuitive, but it really is best practice. Users will complain about errors that they see, and visible exceptions and crashes will upset them and reduce their confidence in your application.

However, exceptions that they don't see still happened, and because you've silently trucked through them whatever caused them *is still there*. Silent exceptions cause data to be lost or corrupted. They cause the kind of bugs that you only find out about after 6 months in production. They cause the kind of bugs you can get sued over.

Users will forgive you for obvious errors that you fix quick, they will leave and never come back if you lose data and don't immediately know about it.

Ok, so that all said, the errors you seem to be highlighting are *asynchronous*, and related to a problem sometimes described as *callback hell*.

In your screenshot the error is from an HTTP GET request - this will typically be a method where you make an AJAX request, have a callback to fire when it succeeds, but don't have a callback to handle the exception.

Angular2 uses promises, which is the next error line of your screenshot. Promises wrap those callbacks and allow you to chain them - they really help with *callback hell*, but they're not a magic bullet: you have to make sure that every `.then()` has an error handler or a following `.catch()`.

However, there is an even better way: with Angular2 you can use TypeScript, and that means you can use `async` and `await`. These are syntactic sugar for promises, but they also work with `try`-`catch` to make error handling of asynchronous exceptions *much* easier.

I've [blogged about that in a lot more detail than I can fit here](https://www.evolutionjobs.com/uk/media/async-programming-in-js-76719/).

**TL;DR:** in Angular2 use `async`/`await` (with TS transpilation if you need it) to make sure that your `Promise` and callback exceptions make it back up, and then handle what you expect/can work around and visibly crash for what you can't.